# Как хранить и вызывать функции по thiscall?

Tags: c++, c++17

Я делаю систему регистрации колбэков от аппаратных устройств и перевожу их на c++. Есть библиотечная функция со слабым связыванием в c-файле, которая вызывается при наступлении какого-то аппаратного события. Я её в своём файле переопределяю, и перенаправляю вызов в метод некоторого класса.

То есть имеется вызываемая функция (`Callable`), и объект класса, которому эта функция принадлежит (`Object`). Эти две сущности надо как-то хранить с тем, чтобы потом можно было вызвать.

Варианты с использованием `std::function` и подобных типов не подходят, так как они выделяют память в куче. Вот что у меня получилось:

```
template<class Callable, class Object>
struct Callback {
    
    Callback(Callable f, Object o) :
        func(f),
        object(o)
        {}
    
    Callable func;
    Object object;
};

class CallbackRegistry {
public:
    template<class Callable, class Object>
    static void setCallback(Object object, Callable func)
    {
        Callback1<Callable, Object> = Callback<Callable, Object>(func, object);
    }
    
    //Здесь надо хранить объект this и функцию. Возможно, надо уйти от шаблонности.
    template<class Callable, class Object>
    static Callback<Callable, Object> Callback1; 
};


template<class Callable, class Object>
Callback<Callable, Object> CallbackRegistry::Callback1 = Callback<Callable, Object>(nullptr, nullptr);

//Эта функция вызывается аппаратно. В библиотечном файле она объявлена со слабым связыванием.
void HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    //Как определить эти типы? Если уходить от шаблонности переменной Callback1, то их здесь не будет
    std::invoke(CallbackRegistry::Callback1<?, ?>.func, 
                CallbackRegistry::Callback1<?, ?>.object /* this */);
}

CallbackRegistry::setCallback(someObject, comeMethodOfObject);
```

Проблема в том, что для реализации нужного поведения надо как-то избавиться от шаблонности в переменной `Callback1`. Где-то отдельно хранить тип? Но как - я пока не понимаю.

Comment: Закрывающих прошу объяснить, чего не хватает.

Comment: В коде тьма какой-то совершенно не нужной специфики (в частности, каких-то диких имён). Он не соответствует тому, что называется [mcve].

Comment: Исправил пример.

Comment: Если вообще перейти на callback функции с прототипом `extern "C" foo(...);", то может быть картина упростится?

Comment: @avp, что имеете в виду? Главная задача здесь - переход от функций C к классам C++. Я могу преобразовать к типу `void*` указатель на функцию и на объект класса, но можно ли по таким данным вручную сконструировать thiscall? Скорее всего, это будет какой-то грубый хак. Chorkov, на мой взгляд, предложил элегантное решение, и меня очень интересует комментарий минусатора.

Comment: Я не минусовал, все что сказал в комментарии, так это то, что возможно вообще отказ от классов С++ позволит решать такие задачи более естественным способом

Comment: Нет, хоть этот проект и embedded, но я решил писать его на C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Храните в callback-е данные конкретного типа, а не шаблонные. Можно выделить специальный интерфейс для этого.

```
struct ICallable
{
    virtual void operator() (void) const =0;
};

// std::function<void(void)> - своими руками, без выделения памятию.
template<class Lambda>
struct Callable : ICallable {
    Lambda lambda;
    Callable(Lambda lambda) : lambda(lambda) {}
    void operator() (void) const { lambda(); }
};

class CallbackRegistry {
public:
    // Сделаем универсально, для любого invorkable набора аргументов.
    template<class... Args>
    static void setCallback(Args...args)
    {
        auto binded=[=](){ std::invoke(args...); }; // сворачиваем набор аргументов в один.
        static Callable<decltype(binded)> instance( binded ); // создаем экземпляр Callable. 
        assert(callback==nullptr);
        callback=&instance;
    }
    static ICallable* callback; 
};
ICallable* CallbackRegistry::callback = nullptr;

void HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if(CallbackRegistry::callback!=nullptr)
        (*CallbackRegistry::callback)();
}   


struct Test
{
    void foo() {}
} test;
CallbackRegistry::setCallback(  &Test::foo, & test );
```

Comment: А здесь почему минус? Решение рабочее.